# Clues on how to solve these types of problems within 2-3 minutes for competitive exams

Tags: integration, derivatives, definite-integrals

$$\int_0^{102}\left(\prod_{k=1}^{100}(x-k)\right)\left(\sum_{k=1}^{100}\frac1{x-k}\right)\,dx$$

I've tried solving this problem but only thing that comes to my mind is the manual integration by multiplication of the expressions which will literally take much longer than the allotted time for competitive exams  Now this is a homework and exercises problem but I'd be glad if I could get some clues on how to solve this problem.

Comment: My guess is the integrand is anti-symmetric about $x=51$ so that the integral is zero.

Comment: The answer given is 101!-100! but no solutions also i can't find such problem online to learn

Comment: How about using the reverse product rule?

Comment: As a _**problem solving tip**_, always write out the first few terms of the series, make observations and hypothesize a probable path to the solution.

Comment: Anybody gives me such an exercise, I start by replacing 100 by 3 (or even 2), this gives something which is far more easy to handle, and I have something I can learn from.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

**Hint**:

By the product rule you have the following result:

$$\dfrac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}\prod_{k=1}^{100}(x-k)=\left(\prod_{k=1}^{100}(x-k)\right)\left(\sum_{k=1}^{100}\dfrac{1}{(x-k)}\right)$$

Integrate both sides from $0$ to $102$, use the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus and you'll be done in no time.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90369/discussion-on-answer-by-paras-khosla-clues-on-how-to-solve-these-types-of-proble).

Answer (score 11):

Here's a quick hint: if you differentiate the product in the integrand, you get the entire integrand so by the fundamental theorem of calculus you can evaluate this very fast.

Comment: So how do i diffrentiate it? would'nt it take longer? I might sound stupid to you but I am new to these

Comment: I think Paras said it--the product rule gives it to you.

Comment: Please review the [EOQS](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508) It states not to give answer to contextless question and the OP hasn't shown much of context